# MacBook Pro and Backtrack 5R1 Configuration

Tags: macos, multi-boot, backtrack

I have a Macbook pro Quad core (2.2/8gb ram/750gb hdd). I have went through tons of forums on the Internet, but none of them seemed to be updated for the current Backtrack 5R1, or the question of getting it to correctly work on the MBP. Can anyone help?

I don’t have a USB Dongle, and I want to be able to use the internal airport extreme wireless of the MBP to use BT 5R1. I have downloaded Backtrack 5R1 onto VMWare Fusion, and got it up and running, but to no avail. It keeps recognizing my card as a Ethernet connection. Kismac wont recognize the card either. So what I am asking for is this:

1. The proper “download method.” for Backtrack 5R1 to my MacBook Pro. (YES I AM WILLING TO RE-DOWNLOAD BT 5R1). The Complete process from start to finish, UP TO DATE, from someone who has done this using an MBP Running Lion OSX.
2. The proper tweaks, settings, or commands to get my airport extreme wireless card to work (it is BROADCOM 4331 I think). The wireless connection I need to use the tools on both Backtrack 5R1 and Kismac. I mainly need to test WEP cracking on my network for security.
3. The difference between running BT 5R1 on VMWARE Fusion and running from downloading it directly to the MBP, if there is, How to download it directly to the MBP?

Answer (score 3):

1. you are doing it correctly. VMWARE images will see the macbook's wireless as an ethernet connection. this is expected, and can't be helped.
2. see above.
3. the difference will be utilizing actual hardware vs emulating a system in VMWARE. backtrack is built on ubuntu, so you could in theory follow many of the tutorials for installing ubuntu bare metal on a macbook pro.

**note: if your mac is newer than spring 2011, the UEFI will not allow you to boot ANY operating system other than OSX, or Windows 7 via bootcamp bare-metal (not even XP!) You're stuck with OSX.

keep in mind that mac hardware is generally not compatible with linux setups - you CAN get linux working, but in my experience ive always found it somewhat flaky on mac hardware.

a good place to start is here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro

and you may want to check out refit (http://refit.sourceforge.net/) for dual booting.

**above all: MAKE A BACKUP OF YOUR SYSTEM. it's far too easy to completely hose your laptop mucking about with dualbooting, especially in OSX.

ive found the best bet for running linux of any kind on a laptop is a thinkpad.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you still can boot Linux on OS X in the newer machines. The issue is with the GPT that Mac uses and the MBR that Linux uses.

The Fix: Find the **MAC VERSION** of the command line tool "gptsync". Once you have installed Linux, you should boot into OS X and run this tool. After that, you should be ok. This worked for me.